# RMI: Client sends a message to Server

Tags: java, client-server, rmi

I have a problem understanding, on how to make my client to send the object to a server. 
So I have one interface called "RMIInterface" and client "RMIClient" and server "RMIServer" classes:

**RMIInterface**

```
public interface RMIInterface extends Remote {

   public String getMessage(String text) throws RemoteException;

}
```

**RMIClient**

```
public class RMIClient {

    private void connectToServer() {
        try {
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("127.0.0.1", 1099);
            RMI rmi = (RMI) registry.lookup("server");
            System.out.println("Connected to Server");

            String text = rmi.getMessage("RMITest Message");
            System.out.println(text);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RMIClient client = new RMIClient();
        client.connectToServer();
    }

}
```

**RMIServer**

```
public class RMIServer extends UnicastRemoteObject implements RMIInterface {

    public RMIServer() throws RemoteException {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public String getMessage(String text) throws RemoteException {
        return "Your message is: " + text;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
            registry.rebind("server", new RMIServer());
            System.out.println("Server started!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

With this program I can connect to a Server with a Client, and print in Client console a message.
My quesiton is, how can I send message from a client to a server, and print that message in server console output? Please make the simplest code example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `sendMessage()` method to your interface.

Comment: Ok, but how can I connect to server and send object to server inside that method? What code should I write inside of sendMessage()?

Comment: Could You please provide me a code, then I can accept your answer. Thank you!

Comment: Come off it. I've told you what to do. I expect any competent programmer to be able to turn that into a method declaration.

Answer (score 7):

Although it has been over a year, I share solution in case someone comes here looking to solve the question as I did yesterday.

**RMIInterface**

```
import java.rmi.*;

public interface RMIInterface extends Remote {

    public void sendMessage(String text) throws RemoteException;

    public String getMessage(String text) throws RemoteException; 

}
```

**RMIClient**

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.registry.*;

public class RMIClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String text = "RMI Test Message";
        RMIInterface rmi = null;

        try {
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("127.0.0.1", 1099);
            rmi = (RMIInterface) registry.lookup("server");
            System.out.println("Connected to Server");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (rmi != null) {
            try {
                rmi.sendMessage(text);
                System.out.println(rmi.getMessage(text));
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Finished");
        }
    }
}
```

**RMIServer**

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.registry.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;

public class RMIServer implements RMIInterface {

    @Override
    public void sendMessage(String s) throws RemoteException {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    @Override
    public String getMessage(String text) throws RemoteException {
        return "Your message is: " + text;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Registry reg = null;
        try {
            reg = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Could not create the registry.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        RMIServer serverObject = new RMIServer();
        System.out.println("Waiting...");
        try {
            reg.rebind("server", (RMIInterface) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(serverObject, 0));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Failed to register the server object.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not gonna provide you the code, cause you already have it. I'm gonna provide you with a solution:

You already have a "channel" where you send a unidirectional message, SERVER -> CLIENT. 
If you want to send a message from you server to your client, your CLIENT must be a SERVER too.

Comment: He wants to send a message from the client to the server. He is already sending a message from the server to the client, which disproves your last sentence.